# Recover files from fried Macbook - receive access denied

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, macbook

I have a friend that has a Macbook that no longer works, however the hard drive is still functioning properly. I took the hard drive out of the laptop and installed it into a desktop PC, and then booted to Linux Mint from a disk (I don't have a docking station). I then inserted a Flash drive to copy the files to. However when I open the home directory on the hard drive, I am getting an access denied. I can browse all through the disk except the home directory where all of their data is located. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get by this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken ownership of the drive? http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/32899-63-ownership-entire-drive

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an access denied. I can browse all through the disk except the home directory where all of their data is located. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get by this?

OS X is a UNIX-based operating system and HFS+ (the file system) supports **permissions.** Normally, each user is assigned a UID. On Linux distributions, especially those based on Ubuntu, the UIDs are sequential. The first user account you create is `1000`, the next one is `1001` and so on.

On OS X this might be different. Let's say for example that your friend's user had UID `50`. When you mount the drive with Linux Mint, it sees that the directory you are trying to access is owned by user `50` and you are `1000`. If said directory doesn't have the `o+r` permission (read permission for "other" users) it won't let you see it.

Now, the easiest thing to do in this case is running the file manager **as root.** Which file manager it is really depends on the Linux Mint variant you used. It could be `nautilus`, `dolphin`, `caja`, `pcmanfm` or anything else.

For example:

```
sudo nautilus /
```

On many Linux distributions, you can try to open a directory with the default file manager using `xdg-open` even if you don't know its name:

```
sudo xdg-open /
```

Beware: you now have full permissions on the files on any connected drive. Pay attention on what changes you perform.